# Finding Linear Operator for a given Basis

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory, functional-equations

Consider a linear operator $$L: \lbrace f: \Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R} \rbrace \rightarrow   \lbrace f: \Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R} \rbrace $$

For example

$$ L(f) = f(x+1) - f(x)$$

Define the $M-\text{kernel}$ as the set $\lbrace x: L(x) = M \rbrace$
One can seek the 0-kernel of $L$, call it $M_1$ and then ask for the $M_1-\text{kernel}$, call that result $M_2$ etc... If we consider one representative from each set we form a basis for our underlying space, An example basis for the set of functions is given below:

$$ 0, 1, x, \frac{1}{2}x(x-1), \frac{1}{6}(x)(x-1)(x-2) ...  $$

A more familiar example if $L(x) = \frac{df}{dx}$ is the basis

$$ 0, 1, x, \frac{1}{2}x^2 , \frac{1}{6}x^3 ... $$

So here's the question,

If I'm given an order basis

$$ w_1(x), w_2(x), w_3(x) ... $$

How do I find a linear operator L such that $L(w_i(x)) = w_{i-1}(x)$ and $L(w_1(x)) = 0 $

For example if given:
$$ 0, 1, x, \frac{1}{2}x^2 , \frac{1}{6}x^3 ... $$

One possible answer would be differentiation, but suppose Instead I give

$$ 0 ,1, x, \frac{1}{2}x(x-1), \frac{1}{6}x(x-1)(x-4), \frac{1}{24}x(x-1)(x-4)(x-9) ... $$

How do I find the linear operator that gives rise to this?

Comment: Well, if the given sequence is known to be a basis, you already know what the linear operator is: it's the one that acts on the given basis in the mentioned way. As the terms of the sequence form a basis, the set of their linear combinations is dense, and you may be able to extend the operator you have to some extra points continuously. So, I don't understand what you mean when you say "find the linear operator". Of course, you shouldn't expect a generic operator to be given in some nice closed form. Being specified on some specific basis is what defines a generic linear operator. You have it!